# kubernetes config map data value externalisation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I'm installing fluent-bit in our k8s cluster.  I have the helm chart for it on our repo, and argo is doing the deployment.

Among the resources in the helm chart is a config-map with data value as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit
  labels:
    app: fluent-bit
data:
...
  output-s3.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name s3
        Match *
        bucket bucket/prefix/random123/test
        region ap-southeast-2
...
```

My question is how can I externalize the value for the bucket so it's not hardcoded (please note  that the bucket value has random numbers)? As the s3 bucket is being created by a separate app that gets ran on the same master node, the randomly generated s3 bucket name is available as environment variable, e.g. doing "echo $s3bucketName" on the node would give the actual value).

I have tried doing below on the config map but it didn't work and is just getting set as it is when inspected on pod:

```
bucket $(echo $s3bucketName)
```

Using helm, I know it can be achieved something like below and then can populate using scripting something like `helm --set` to set the value from environment variable.  But the deployment is happening auto through argocd so it's not like there is a place to do `helm --set` command or please let me know if otherwise.

```
bucket {{.Values.s3.bucket}}
```

TIA

Comment: the scope is narrow, I would create a init container, which would take care of creating this `configmap` , where I can access the variable.

Comment: ArgoCD can override the parameter values with `argo app set` command. (more [here](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/helm/#helm-parameters)).

Comment: @p10l, thanks, would you know equivalent yaml for that? as argo syncing is automated and we don't do argo cli.  also can the values to set be from an system env variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FluentBit you should be able to [use environment variables](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/configuring-fluent-bit/variables) such as:

```
  output-s3.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name s3
        Match *
        bucket ${S3_BUCKET_NAME}
        region ap-southeast-2
```

You can then set the environment variable on your Helm values. Depending on the chart you are using and how values are passed you may have to perform a different setup, but for example using the [official FluentBit charts](https://github.com/fluent/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/fluent-bit) with a `values-prod.yml` like:

```
env:
- name: S3_BUCKET_NAME
  value: "bucket/prefix/random123/test"
```

Using ArgoCD, you probably have a Git repository where Helm values files are defined (like `values-prod.yml`) and/or an ArgoCD application defining values direct. For example, if you have an ArgoCD application defined such as:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  # [...]
spec:
  source:
    # ...
    helm:      
      # Helm values files for overriding values in the helm chart
      valueFiles:
      # You can update this file
      - values-prod.yaml

      # Helm values
      values: |
        # Or update values here
        env:
        - name: S3_BUCKET_NAME
          value: "bucket/prefix/random123/test"
        # ...
```

You should be able to update either `values-prod.yml` on the repository used by ArgoCD or update directly `values:` with you environment variable

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `helm install` you can use `helm template ... --set ... > out.yaml` to locally render your chart in a yaml file. This file can then be processed by Argo.

[Docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/)

Comment: Argo is on automated sync, I don't run cli for argo nor helm, it's all declarative yaml.  Any equivalent of --set that can be sourced from system env var?